# Adding extra entry in a multi-indexed pandas dataframe from another multi-indexed pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a multi-indexed pandas dataframe that  I have used the `groupby` method followed by the `describe` method on to give me the following:

```
    grouped= self.HK_data.groupby(level=[0,1])
    summary= grouped.describe()
```

which gives:

```
Antibody        Time                
Customer_Col1A2 0    count  3.000000
                     mean   0.757589
                     std    0.188750
                     min    0.639933
                     25%    0.648732
                     50%    0.657532
                     75%    0.816417
                     max    0.975302
                10   count  3.000000
                     mean   0.716279
                     std    0.061939
                     min    0.665601
                     25%    0.681757
                     50%    0.697913
                     75%    0.741618
                     max    0.785324
                     ...   .........
```

I have calculated the `SEM` using:

```
    SEM=grouped.mean()/(numpy.sqrt(grouped.count()))
```

Giving:

```
Antibody                 Time          
Customer_Col1A2          0     0.437394
                         10    0.413544
                         120   0.553361
                         180   0.502792
                         20    0.512797
                         240   0.514609
                         30    0.505618
                         300   0.481021
                         45    0.534658
                         5     0.425800
                         60    0.430633
                         90    0.525115
                         ...  .........
```

How do I `concat` these two frames such that the SEM's become another entry of the summary statistics?

So something like:

```
Antibody        Time                
Customer_Col1A2 0    count  3.000000
                     mean   0.757589
                     std    0.188750
                     min    0.639933
                     25%    0.648732
                     50%    0.657532
                     75%    0.816417
                     max    0.975302
                     SEM    0.437394
                10   count  3.000000
                     mean   0.716279
                     std    0.061939
                     min    0.665601
                     25%    0.681757
                     50%    0.697913
                     75%    0.741618
                     max    0.785324
                     SEM    0.413544
```

I've tried `pandas.concat` but this didn't give me what I want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you first add third level of `MultiIndex` , assign new index by [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html) and last use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
HK_data = pd.DataFrame({'Antibody':['Customer_Col1A2','Customer_Col1A2','Customer_Col1A2'],
                   'Time':[0,10,10],
                   'Col':[7,8,9]})
HK_data = HK_data.set_index(['Antibody','Time'])
print (HK_data)
                      Col
Antibody        Time     
Customer_Col1A2 0       7
                10      8
                10      9
```

```
grouped= HK_data.groupby(level=[0,1])
summary= grouped.describe()
print (summary)
                                 Col
Antibody        Time                
Customer_Col1A2 0    count  1.000000
                     mean   7.000000
                     std         NaN
                     min    7.000000
                     25%    7.000000
                     50%    7.000000
                     75%    7.000000
                     max    7.000000
                10   count  2.000000
                     mean   8.500000
                     std    0.707107
                     min    8.000000
                     25%    8.250000
                     50%    8.500000
                     75%    8.750000
                     max    9.000000

SEM=grouped.mean()/(np.sqrt(grouped.count()))
#change multiindex
new_index = list(zip(SEM.index.get_level_values('Antibody'),
                     SEM.index.get_level_values('Time'), 
                     ['SEM'] * len(SEM.index)))
SEM.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_index, names=('Antibody','Time', None))

print (SEM)
                               Col
Antibody        Time              
Customer_Col1A2 0    SEM  7.000000
                10   SEM  6.010408
```

```
df = pd.concat([summary, SEM]).sort_index()
print (df)
                                 Col
Antibody        Time                
Customer_Col1A2 0    25%    7.000000
                     50%    7.000000
                     75%    7.000000
                     SEM    7.000000
                     count  1.000000
                     max    7.000000
                     mean   7.000000
                     min    7.000000
                     std         NaN
                10   25%    8.250000
                     50%    8.500000
                     75%    8.750000
                     SEM    6.010408
                     count  2.000000
                     max    9.000000
                     mean   8.500000
                     min    8.000000
                     std    0.707107
```